# Javascript - prompt keeps coming back after Ok is pressed

Tags: javascript, click, reload, prompt

I have the following JavaScript configuration. It works well when it loads and keeps working well the first time I click on the button with id `buttonKernel`. This should run the function `onPageLoad`, which resets a grid presented on screen and reload the event handlers. The second time I click the button thought, after clicking OK on the prompt, it keeps prompting again. If I insist, it will eventually work. 
I'm new to JavaScript, so that I don't know if this self calling function can be at the root of the problem.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    onPageLoad(16);
});

function onPageLoad(size){
    genDiv(size);
    $('.gridSquare').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });
    $('#buttonKernel').click(function(){
        $(".gridSquare").css('background-color', 'yellow');

        var input = prompt ("Enter a size for the grid", "16");        
        size = checkInp(input);
        var list = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
        for (var i = list.length - 1; 0 <= i; i--)
        {
            if (list[i] && list[i].parentElement)
            list[i].parentElement.removeChild(list[i]);
        };  
        onPageLoad(size);
    });
}
```

Comment: what is `genDiv(size);` doing? Once I remove that line of code, it works fine.

Comment: It generates a new grid by creating new divs. I think Jaromanda X must be right, yet I didn't try a solution yet. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

every time you click, you add another click event handler.

Comment: I think you are right. Thinking about it, when I clicked for the second time, we now have two handlers, so that the window will open twice. I repeated the same function because the hover event was being deactivated, since the grid in which it acts is created again, but the button isn't. I will try to change that later. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working fine for me?

http://jsfiddle.net/8atqub5k/1/

There are two unknown functions... genDiv(size) and checkInp(input)  I have no clue what those do.  Note: if there is a javascript error in either of those functions, generally javascript won't function at all on the rest of the site.

Are you aware of the Chrome browser Developer Tools?  Way awesome tool for troubleshooting javascript (or html and CSS ) errors...

```
<style>
.gridSquare{
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     background-color: blue;
}
</style>

<button id="buttonKernel">Click here</button>
<div class="gridSquare">Test</div>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    onPageLoad(16);
});

function onPageLoad(size){
    //genDiv(size);
    $('.gridSquare').hover(function(){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    });

    $('#buttonKernel').click(function(){
        $(".gridSquare").css('background-color', 'yellow');

        var input = prompt ("Enter a size for the grid", "16");        
        size = checkInp(input); // what is this function?
        var list = document.getElementsByClassName("row");
        for (var i = list.length - 1; 0 <= i; i--)
        {
            if (list[i] && list[i].parentElement)
            list[i].parentElement.removeChild(list[i]);
        };  
        // onPageLoad(size);  // don't need this!
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Oops. @JaromandaX is exactly right. The onPageLoad(size) shouldn't be called again.  onPageLoad is NOT a recursive function.. :^)

Comment: Yes, I think he is right. Anyway, thanks for the hint on the tool.